# Токен Google Drive живет один час

Tags: python, google-drive

Всех приветствую. Возникла проблема. Использую Google Drive API.
Час всё нормально, но после выдается ошибка

> The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.

Не понимаю как пофиксить.
Из видео того, кто обучал библиотеке скачал файл

[Ссылка на код](https://pastebin.com/AKwzEqbT)

Создал OAuth 2.0 Client с настройкой под Web Client

Использую в телеграмм боте, пишу на Aiogram *вдруг это как-то важно*.

Вопрос как это решить, и если есть возможность сгенерировать этот refresh_token, то как это сделать

Надеюсь на помощь